# datetime - How to strip just date and validate the date

Tags: selenium, validation, datetime, strptime

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from datetime import datetime

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ="C:/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.timestampconvert.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
time.sleep(2)

date_displayed = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/div/span[5]')

print('Date displayed on page:', date_displayed.text)

try:
    datetime.strptime(date_displayed.text, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    print('The date format {} is valid.'.format(date_displayed.text))
except ValueError:
    print('The date {} is invalid'.format(date_displayed.text))
```

The above code executes fine BUT It doesn't do what I am expecting
1. I just want the date to be displayed and strip time, but it displays both date and time?
2. How do i validate the date and month?

For example
If date is displayed as 24/05/2020 - It should pass because expected date format is DD-MM-YYYY
If date is displayed as 06/16/2020 - It should Fail because expected date format is DD-MM-YYYY but actual format displayed is MM/DD/YYYY

--
I have a requirements to test specific date formats on my applications and i want to specify 
first digit is always 'DD' and it range from 1 to 31
second digit is always 'MM' and it range from 1 to 12

it should validate and should pass / fail the test accordingly.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

why not

```
try:
    mydate=date_display.test.split(" ")[0]
    datetime.strptime(mydate, '%d-%m-%Y')
    print('The date format {} is valid.'.format(mydate))
except ValueError:
    print('The date {} is invalid'.format(mydate))
```

Comment: Thanks I am now able to split and just display the date only .However I am still looking at how do i validate the date format it self.